# Can a F1 student go to Dominican Republic?

Tags: international-travel, dominican-republic, albanian-citizens

I am a F1 student going to college in the US. I am from Albania and have an Albanian passport. I want to go on vacation to Dominican Republic but am I allowed to leave the US and go there?

Comment: The US has no exit checks; anyone can leave the US at any time. Are you asking about entering the Dominican Republic? or re-entering the US?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are allowed to go to the Dominican Republic.  To re-enter the US, though, you need a valid F-1 visa.  If your visa has expired, you have two options:

1. If your trip to the Dominican Republic is 30 days or shorter, you may be able to use [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/automatic-revalidation.html).
2. If your trip to the Dominican Republic is longer than 30 days, or if you cannot use automatic revalidation for some other reason, you can apply for a new F-1 visa at the [US embassy in Santo Domingo](http://santodomingo.usembassy.gov/contact.html).